# Entries from matrix should not appear in loop

Tags: matrix, entry, loop, join

- I have a Matrix with an entry field.
- I have a Loop which is looping entries out of a section.

Goal: The entries from the matrix should not appear in the loop of the section.  So the Matrix defines Starred Member Profiles and the loop trough the section is a teamlist, but the two starred profiles should not appear in there.

I tried something like this but i stuck right now...

```
{# Get the profiles which are in the matrix #}
{% set highlightProfiles = entry.highlightProfiles.all() %}

{% for profile in highlightProfiles %}

 {# Just a test to see the ID of each single entry #}
 {{ profile.hightlightProfileTeaser.one().id() }} 

 {% set highlightProfileSingleIds = profile.hightlightProfileTeaser.all().ids() %}

{% endfor %}

{# set something up for the entry ids which should not join in the endloop #}
{% set highlightProfileIdsString = highlightProfileSingleIds | join(', not ') %}

{% set teamMembers = craft.entries({
 section: 'profiles',
 limit: 50 
}) %}

{% set allProfilesWithOutHighlights = teamMembers.id('and, not '~highlightProfileIdsString).orderBy('title asc') %}
{% for member in allOtherMembers.orderBy('title asc').all()  %}
 {{ member.title }} {{ member.id() }} {{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track, to “collect” the entry IDs you have to use the `merge` filter in your Matrix loop though.

```
{% set highlightProfileSingleIds = [] %}

{% for profile in highlightProfiles %}
    {% set ids = profile.hightlightProfileTeaser.ids() %}
    {% set highlightProfileSingleIds = highlightProfileSingleIds|merge(ids) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: works! thank yoou!